# Kotlin represent array with boolean indexing

Tags: arrays, kotlin, boolean, kotlin-extension

I want to have a 2x2 2d array of int in kotlin but the indexing should be using booleans like this:

```
      | true | false |
----------------------
true  |  0   |  75   |
----------------------
false |  1   |  34   |
```

I know I can use a 2d array of int but not sure how to represent the indexing via booleans.

Any help much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is a good idea in general, but Kotlin does [allow this kind of operator overloading](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/operator-overloading.html) (`Array<IntArray>` is the Kotlin type for 2d array of ints):

```
operator fun Array<IntArray>.get(x: Boolean, y: Boolean) = this[if (x) 1 else 0][if (y) 1 else 0]

val array: Array<IntArray> = ....
array[true, false]
```

Comment: can you make this a function so it uses {} not =

Comment: and is it possible to make this generic so the 2d array can be of ints or double?

Comment: You have to copy the code with `DoubleArray` instead of `IntArray` (and other types if you need them). `Array<Array<T>>` is the generic option, but it has overhead: it ends up represented as a 2d array of `Object`s. See https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/basic-types.html.